# Escaping parentheses in contact search API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to search for a contact with a phone number of the following format:
`(XXX) XXX-XXXX`

I tried the following query and get no results:

```
/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=10&$search="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"
```

I also tried it with URL encoded parenthesis and also get no results:

```
/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=10&$search="%28XXX%29 XXX-XXXX"
```

The only thing that worked for me is:

```
/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=10&$search="*XXX*XXX*XXXX"
```

However, with the last one I'm concerned that it could return bad results in some cases where there might be some other numbers in the wildcard positions.

Is there a proper way to do this search?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using filter query instead of search, that way you might be able to scope the search just to the phone field.